# How to freeze columns in older version of jqGrid? I have version (3.5.1)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid

I want to freeze multiselect checkbox column of jqGrid I want functionality like this http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FrozenMultiselectColumns.htm

I know how to use this in new versions of jqGrid. But I have a project in which all functionality are developed using jqGrid version 3.5.1

On serverside I use Struts2 with mybatis

Frozen column functionality are come in version 4.3.0

So, Have you any clue about how achieve this in my version of jqgrid ?

Comment: The version 3.5.1 is dead for a long time. You have to update jqGrid. I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.1. Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. It have very good support of frozen columns.

Comment: It's very difficult now to use new features for autos with steam motor. It will be much easier it you would use the auto with petrol, diesel or electric motor.

Comment: Yes, you are right Oleg. But I have already a big project developed using version 3.5.1 so, currently I can't update the jqGrid version it may affect older functionality in current project

Comment: Sorry, but you should thought about that many years ago. Even 5 years ago the version 3.5.1 was dead. It's more as 7 years old. Sorry, but it's like 1000 year in the web development. You have no chance to hold the zombie alive. You have to migrate to new version of jqGrid.